# How to avoid setting the on click bind event every time the function is ran

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay

So I made this overlay function, and I've also made it close on click on the overlay its self. Problem is I bind the click event every time I run the function (`$overlay.click(function() {...}`), and I think this is bad for performance. Any ideas?

```js
function fluidOverlayShow(action, currentElement) {
  var $overlay = $('#fluid-overlay');
  if (action == 'open') {
    $overlay.click(function() {
      emgFluidOverlayShow('close', currentElement);
    });
    $(currentElement).addClass('fluid-bring-front');
    $overlay.addClass('fluid-anim-overlay');
    $overlay.data('statuson', true);
  } else if (action == 'close') {
    $overlay.removeClass('fluid-anim-overlay');
    $overlay.data('statuson', false);
    $('.fluid-header').find('.fluid-bring-front').removeClass('fluid-bring-front');
  }
}

$('#overlay_test').mouseover(function() {
  fluidOverlayShow('open', '#overlay_test');
});

$('#overlay_test').mouseout(function() {
  fluidOverlayShow('close');
});
```

```css
#fluid-overlay {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#overlay_test {
  position: relative;
}
  

#fluid-overlay.fluid-anim-overlay {
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation: fade-in-overlay 0.2s 1;
    -moz-animation:    fade-in-overlay 0.2s 1;
    animation:         fade-in-overlay 0.2s 1;
}

.fluid-bring-front {
    z-index: 1100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;" id="overlay_test">Overlay test</a>
<div id="fluid-overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you keep the `click` event outside?

Comment: Oh, yeah, that could work. Thank you!

Comment: anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutely have to keep the click event in the function then use `.on()` and `.off()` and then define `.off("click")` before you define `on("click")` like this:

```
$overlay.off("click").on("click", function() {
  emgFluidOverlayShow('close', currentElement);
});
```

This will remove the event binding before it adds it.

You can even namespace the click event like this so it only removes that instance of click (in case other events get added elsewhere):

```
$overlay.off("click.fluidOverlayClose").on("click.fluidOverlayClose", function() {
  emgFluidOverlayShow('close', currentElement);
});
```

## Or...

...do as **Guruprasad Rao** suggests and move it out of the function (which is a much better way of handling it).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative implementation uses [jQuery's `.on()` method combined with event delgation](http://api.jquery.com/on/). What his means is you allow the click event to bubble up through the DOM to a parent element that will always be there that will capture and process the event rather than having to rebind it to the dynamic element everytime it's created.

This would look something like

```
 $("body").on("click","#fluid-overlay",function() {
     //code goes here
    });
```

Comment: I think .on is almost as heavy on performance :) or am I wrong?

Comment: It depends on how far up the DOM tree you go and how many child elements you attach the on event to has. If you only go up one or two levels and so that element only has a handful of child elements that could trigger events then the overhead is small, if you do happen to go up to the body and the page has 10's of thousands of child elements then you might reach some performance concerns.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it cleared up a lot about jquery .on :)